# String / char * concatinate, C

Tags: c, malloc, concatenation, strcat

Am trying to open a file(Myfile.txt) and concatenate each line to a single buffer, but am getting unexpected output. The problem is,my buffer is not getting updated with the last concatenated lines. Any thing missing in my code?

**Myfile.txt**   (The file to open and read)

```
Good morning line-001:
Good morning line-002:
Good morning line-003:
Good morning line-004:
Good morning line-005:
.
.
.
```

Mycode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   /* Define a temporary variable */
   char Mybuff[100]; // (i dont want to fix this size, any option?)
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len=0;
   FILE *fp;
   fp =fopen("Myfile.txt","r");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
        printf("the file couldn't exist\n");
        return;
   }
   while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1 )
   {
       //Any function to concatinate the strings, here the "line"
       strcat(Mybuff,line);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   printf("Mybuff is: [%s]\n", Mybuff);

   return 0;
}
```

Am expecting my output to be:

```
Mybuff is: [Good morning line-001:Good morning line-002:Good morning line-003:Good morning line-004:Good morning line-005:]
```

But, am getting segmentation fault(run time error) and a garbage value. Any think to do? thanks.

Comment: you are experiencing a buffer overflow, with a hardcoded limit of 100. Use pointers, *hint: realloc*

Comment: @t0mm13b: Thank u for replay, but still the same problem! Added Mybuff = realloc(Mybuff, sizeof mybuff), ...can you help me out pls, iam new to C language .

Comment: Read [this Cornell lecture notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2022/2011sp/lectures/lect04.pdf) first!  Get the K&R book also. Start from there.

Comment: K&R are to old to be used anymore. One should forget that ever existed.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `MyBuff` as a pointer, and use dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>    /*  for dynamic memory allocation functions */

char *MyBuff = calloc(1,1);    /* allocate one character, initialised to zero */
size_t length = 1;

while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1 )
{
     size_t newlength = length + strlen(line)
     char *temp = realloc(MyBuff, newlength);
     if (temp == NULL)
     {
          /*  Allocation failed.  Have a tantrum or take recovery action */
     }
     else
     {
          MyBuff = temp;
          length = newlength;
          strcat(MyBuff, temp);
     }
}

/*  Do whatever is needed with MyBuff */

free(MyBuff);

/*   Also, don't forget to release memory allocated by getline() */
```

The above will leave newlines in `MyBuff` for each line read by `getline()`.    I'll leave removing those as an exercise.

Note:  `getline()` is linux, not standard C.   A function like `fgets()` is available in standard C for reading lines from a file, albeit it doesn't allocate memory like `getline()` does.